# Large error after factoring h from fourth-order Runge–Kutta method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

Consider
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x-y, \qquad y(0)=1$$
That has an exact solution $y(t) = 2t+3 e^{-t}-2$. But I want a numerical solution. So I decided to use forth-order [Runge–Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) method

```
function [t,y] = RK4(f ,t, y0 , N)
y(1,:) = y0(:)';
h = (t(2)-t(1))/N; t = t(1)+(0:N)'*h;
for k = 1:N
    k1 = h*f(t(k), y(k,:)); k1 = k1(:)';
    k2 = h*f(t(k)+h/2, y(k,:)+k1/2); k2 = k2(:)';
    k3 = h*f(t(k)+h/2, y(k,:)+k2/2); k3 = k3(:)';
    k4 = h*f(t(k)+h, y(k,:)+k3); k4 = k4(:)';
    y(k + 1,:) = y(k,:)+(k1+2*(k2+k3)+k4)/6;
end
```

That can be written by factoring `h` as

```
function [t,y] = RK4_factor(f ,t, y0 , N)
y(1,:) = y0(:)';
h = (t(2)-t(1))/N; t = t(1)+(0:N)'*h;
for k = 1:N
    k1 = f(t(k), y(k,:)); k1 = k1(:)';
    k2 = f(t(k)+h/2, y(k,:)+k1/2); k2 = k2(:)';
    k3 = f(t(k)+h/2, y(k,:)+k2/2); k3 = k3(:)';
    k4 = f(t(k)+h, y(k,:)+k3); k4 = k4(:)';
    y(k + 1,:) = y(k,:)+h*(k1+2*(k2+k3)+k4)/6;
end
```

But why the results of the above functions are very different

```
>> f = @(t,y) 2*t-y;
>> sol = @(t) 2*t+3*exp(-t)-2;
>> [x y] = RK4(f ,[0 0.5], 1 ,5);
>> [x y_factor] = RK4_factor(f ,[0 0.5], 1 ,5);
>> [x g(0:0.1:0.5)' y y_factor]

ans =

         0    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
    0.1000    0.9145    0.9145    0.9450
    0.2000    0.8562    0.8562    0.9059
    0.3000    0.8225    0.8225    0.8818
    0.4000    0.8110    0.8110    0.8717
    0.5000    0.8196    0.8196    0.8747
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your first code, $h$ is part of $k's$. So you write, for instance, $k_2 = f(t+\frac h2, y + \frac{k_1}{2})$. But in your second piece of code, $h$ is no longer included in $k$, yet you still perform the same calculation for $k_2$ and the rest. To be consistent, you should write $k_2 = f(t+\frac h2, y + h\frac{k_1}{2})$ (note the $h$ inside) and so on.